# Inconsistent UIScrollview margins on iPhone with notch

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I am struggling with `UIScrollView` content margins.

Basically what I am trying to achieve is presenting some content in a scrollview shown inside a modal view.

But I am facing an issue on the iPhones with notch when the content is big enough to require scrolling. When that’s the case the `scrollview.adjustedContentInset` takes account of the safe areas. When it doesn’t require scrolling, the content insets remains zero.

I need that behaviour to be more consistent, is there a way to force using the safe areas or to prevent adjusting the content inset?

---

I tested it in a blank projet and reproduced the issue, basically I have two `ViewControllers`, one that presents the second and the second that dynamically creates a height constraint to a child view to make the content scrollable.

[image: Storyboard view with two view controllers, the first invokes the second with two different sizes]

*(I made a close button that remains at the center of the screen)*

You can see the top margin is different depending on the height of the content.

[image: Two views of the same screen, one with a small content height that overlaps the top bar, the second with a tall content height that sits bellow the screen notch]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I have found a property on `UIScrollView` made explicitly for that purpose: [`contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/2902261-contentinsetadjustmentbehavior).

It’s an enum of type [`UIScrollView.ContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/contentinsetadjustmentbehavior) and it can be one of the four values: `automatic`, `scrollableAxes`, `never` and `always`.

I fixed the issue by using

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .always
}
```

Now the safe area is always present.